# Parsing large text in xml format in Pl/Sql

Tags: plsql, xml-parsing

I have a log table and the table has a varchar2 field which holds xml string like below:
In this example ClientName attribute did not change but Clientsurname changed. 
I want to capture changed columns and their previous and new values.
The log table contains millions of records. 
Which method can you suggest for parsing this data in an efficient way?

```
<r>
   <columntag nameattribute="ClientName">
      <new_value>Jeffrey</new_value>
      <previous_value>Jeffrey</previous_value>
   </columntag>
   <columntag nameattribute="ClientSurname">
      <new_value>Dijk</new_value>
      <previous_value>Disk</previous_value>
   </columntag>
</r>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not 100% sure the below is what you are after but it should give you some ideas about how to go about it. Hope it is helpfull

```
CREATE TABLE "RM4SERV"."LOG_TEST" ( "TESTLOG" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE))

Insert into RM4SERV.LOG_TEST (TESTLOG) values ('<r><columntag nameattribute="ClientName"><new_value>Jeffery</new_value><previous_value>Jeffery</previous_value> </columntag><columntag nameattribute="ClientSurname"><new_value>Dijk</new_value><previous_value>Disk</previous_value></columntag></r>');
Insert into RM4SERV.LOG_TEST (TESTLOG) values ('<r><columntag nameattribute="ClientName"><new_value>Jeffery</new_value><previous_value>Jeffery</previous_value> </columntag><columntag nameattribute="ClientSurname"><new_value>Disk</new_value><previous_value>Disk</previous_value></columntag></r>');
Insert into RM4SERV.LOG_TEST (TESTLOG) values ('<r><columntag nameattribute="ClientName"><new_value>Jeffery</new_value><previous_value>Jim</previous_value> </columntag><columntag nameattribute="ClientSurname"><new_value>Dijks</new_value><previous_value>Diskett</previous_value></columntag></r>');

declare

v_logrec varchar2(4000) := null;  
v_recnum number := 0;

cursor c_logs is
select testlog from log_test;

cursor c_records is 
select extractValue(x.column_value, '/columntag/@nameattribute') as column_name,
         extractValue(x.column_value, '/columntag/new_value') as new_value,
         extractValue(x.column_value, '/columntag/previous_value') as previous_value
from TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(xmltype.createxml(v_logrec), '//columntag'))) x
where extractValue(x.column_value, '/columntag/new_value') != extractValue(x.column_value, '/columntag/previous_value');


begin
for v_log in c_logs loop
  v_logrec := v_log.testlog;
  v_recnum := v_recnum + 1;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_recnum);

  for v_rec in c_records loop
     SYS.dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.column_name || '  :  *' || v_rec.new_value || '*  :  *' || v_rec.previous_value || '*');
  end loop;

end loop;
end;
```

This would give you the below output (so Surname different in first record, nothing different in the second and both different in the third)...

1

ClientSurname  :  *Dijk*  :  *Disk*

2

3

ClientName  :  *Jeffery*  :  *Jim*

ClientSurname  :  *Dijks*  :  *Diskett*